# How to disable the wireless / airplane mode Fn key?

Tags: windows-10, fn-key, airplane-mode

I have a laptop (Acer Aspire 3 N19C1 if that's relevant) mainly for my kid to attend virtual lessons during COVID-19, and by default the <kbd>F2</kbd> key act as a function key to turn Airplane Mode on/off when the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is not pressed simultaneously: 
 [image: Wifi/Airplane Mode Fn Key]

I managed to train my 6-years old kid to join virtual lessons, and try again if something goes wrong, but he is far from troubleshooting network problems; specifically, he will have no clue if he turns on Airplane Mode by pressing that button accidentally nor will I have a way to help remotely.

How can I disable the Airplane Mode function key while keeping the other key functions (e.g. volume, brightness, etc.)?

- I've tried:

  - Modifying UEFI firmware settings: could only change default behaviour to <kbd>F2</kbd> without pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>
  - Disabling *Airplane Mode Controller*, but *Disable Device* is greyed out in: 
     *Device Manager* → *Human Interface Device* → *Acer Airplane Mode Controller*

Comment: There are several (free) software utilities to remap keys. You can also do it via the Registry, it might be tricky for FN keys but it's possible. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I took a look into UEFI configuration (equivalent to BIOS) - no luck.  It could change the default behaviour to F2 without hitting the Fn key.  Also looked into device manager > Human Interface Devices > Acer Airplane Mode Controller, but the "Disable Device" is greyed out.

Comment: Did you try any of the remapping software available? Meanwhile I suggest you switch from Funktion to "F" keys. Although the airplane mode key won't be completely disabled it will require Fn+F2 to be pressed at the same time. (Pressing just the F2 key will function like the regular F2 key). Maybe this will also be a sufficient solution for you.

Comment: Also note: you might need to update the BIOS to get the option to change the default behaviour. (Sometimes you can also disable Fn on the keyboard itself...  look for a patlock-symbol with a little Fn inside, or s.th. similar)

Comment: Beside trying remapping software you could also try Autohotkey (or at least you can use it to "reprogram" desired Fn-Key-Funktions to the regular F-keys, once you deactivated it... hope you can follow ;)  I suppose you found this [webpage](https://www.thesharedweb.com/enable-or-disable-fn-key/) yourself, if not have a look, there are a few more suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

If he doesn't need to use <kbd>F2</kbd>, just pop the key off, put some sponge rubber or resilient foam plastic under the key, sized to make it difficult, but not *too* difficult to press the key, and replace the key cap. On a laptop, it may be easier to *gently* push the foam plastic under the edge of the key using a fine screwdriver blade, being careful not to puncture the membrane below the key.

On my keyboards, I also do this for <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, to avoid accidental SHOUTING.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting and innovative suggestion. I love the answer, thumb up for that! I just hope I had the skills to make the rubber slice and do what you did, without damaging the keyboard. Meanwhile I will keep exploring software ways to do that for a while.